# Controlling app flow in swift

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, startup, control-flow

I am trying to build an app which is dependent on having some items in `CoreData`. I have it syncing with an external data source, which all works fine.

my app uses three methods, and is a single view app:

```
syncData()
createSpinner()
showResult()
```

now `createSpinner` is dependent on having some data in `CoreData` - and only needs to run once

`showResult` is dependent on the 'Spinner' having been created, and is called once on creation to initialize itself, as well as each time my spinner has been spun

I currently have `SyncData` in the `viewDidLoad()`, and the `createSpinner()` in `viewDidAppear()` (as it changes size depending on screen size)

The problem is on first launch the data does not load in time for the `createSpinner()`, and thus the app looks useless. How can I 'wait' for that first sync, or set up something to check there is some data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to force `syncData()` & `createSpinner()` to run in same thread

you can do this by creating a serial queue and dispatch both methods asynchronously into it

```
let serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myview", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dispatch_async(serialQueue) {
        syncData()
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    dispatch_async(serialQueue) {
        createSpinner()
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to use self.syncData() as otherwise xcode complains - but otherwise it works well - thanks

Comment: yeah I forgot this because I was writing the code into the browser not xCode, could you please mark the answer as correct one